# Tape restore giving error incorrect block size - Win2k8

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup-restoration, tape, tapedrive

I'm trying to restore from tape and I am getting an error of incorrect block size. The software I used to backup is called BackupAssist and their support hasnt been the greatest. One weird thing I noticed, after updating the tape drive drivers the block size showed as 512 in the device manager. After running the restore process the block size shows up as 16384. I assume I need to get the block size on the tape drive to match up with the block size on the tape. Anyone have any ideas?

OS: Windows Server 2008 Standard SP1 64 bit
Backup Software: BackupAssist v6
Tape Drive: Quantum DAT72 SCSI

Comment: Almost all modern tape drives support variable block sizes, though many older ones do not. A block size of 10k (10240 bytes) is almost universally supported and commonly used for that reason. If the drive & tape support variable sizes the software *should* pick this up and set the block size appropriately. Best advice I can offer is to hound their support until they get the problem resolved (Quantum drives are well built and supported, that should not be an issue).

Comment: Yes we finally figured out how to manually set the block size and it started restoring but then never finished. I'm guessing the software is pretty bad.